# Model "forgetting" when fine tuning with PEFT LORA

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, sentence-transformers

I am not sure if forgetting is the correct term - it most likely is not. However when fine tuning a `sentence-transformers` model using the `PEFT` library - my model becomes much worse on some of the datasets it originally was trained on.

For example the cosine score for STS16 on `all-MiniLM-L6-v2` was originally `0.78` and by the time I train a few epochs to get the score on the new task to be satisfactory this drops to `0.51`.

This conceptually makes perfect sense - we shift all of the weights to perform the new task, but this renders fine tuning useless as I still need the generic capabilities of the original model.

Is there a way to keep the model from forgetting / diverging the original training without having to also train on all the original data?